# django bash script pass requirements as bash arguments

Tags: django, bash

i have created this bash script to create django projects

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT_NAME=$1
ENV_NAME=$2
PROJECT_DIR="$HOME/$PROJECT_NAME"
echo $PROJECT_NAME;
echo $ENV_NAME;
mkdir -p "$PROJECT_NAME"
cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
python3 -m venv "$ENV_NAME"
. "$PROJECT_DIR/$ENV_NAME/bin/activate"
pip install django django-extensions django-debug-toolbar python-memcached djangorestframework
pip freeze > "$PROJECT_DIR/requirements.txt"
django-admin startproject "$PROJECT_NAME"
mkdir -p public
cd "$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME"
pwd
mkdir -p templates
mkdir -p static
cd templates
touch index.html base.html
cd ..
pwd
cd "$PROJECT_NAME"
mv settings.py settings_base.py
touch settings.py settings_local.py settings_local_sample.py
ls
```

when i run source  file.sh project_name env  it creates the project, i want to pass the requirements of the project as array argument in the bash , how i can do it

Answer (score 1):

The command arguments are in the `$@` array. So you could pass the requirements as additional command line arguments. Then, after you set `PROJECT_NAME` to the first argument, do a `shift` to remove the first argument from `$@`. Then, after you set `ENV_NAME` to the (new) first argument, do a `shift` again. Then, `$@` will contain only the remaining arguments = the list of requirements, so you can use that with `pip install`.

Minor changes in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROJECT_NAME=$1; shift
ENV_NAME=$1; shift
...
pip install "$@"
```

And call the script with:

```
path/to/script.sh the_project_name the_env_name django django-extensions django-debug-toolbar python-memcached djangorestframework
```

If the list of requirements are already in a Bash array in the context where you call the script, then you can pass the array content as command arguments:

```
path/to/script.sh the_project_name the_env_name "${requirements[@]}"
```